# how to create 2 Level Dependent Dropdowns like country and capital using laravel livewire?

Tags: drop-down-menu, laravel-livewire

I am new to laravel livewire and I am trying to create a 2 level dropdown menu (Country and capital) with livewire Components but with no luck I am not getting the resault I want.

This is my `CountryDropdown.php` code:

```php
class CountryDropdown extends Component
{
    public $selectedCountry;
    public function render()
    {
        $countries = Wilaya::all();
        return view('livewire.country-dropdown', compact('countries'));
    }

    public function updatedSelectedCountry($id){
        $this->emit('countrySelected', $id);
    }
}
```

and this is my `CapitalDropdown.php` code:

```php
class CapitalDropdown extends Component
{
    public $selectedCountry;
    public $capitals;

    protected $listeners = ['countrySelected' => 'render'];

    public function render()
    {
        //dd($this->selectedCountry);
        if($this->selectedCountry){
            $this->capitals = Commune::where('wilaya_id', $this->selectedCountry)->get();
        } else {
            $this->capitals = [];
        }
        return view('livewire.capital-dropdown');
    }
}
```

As you can see I am getting all countries in the `CountryDropdown.php` and it's working fine but whenever I Choose A country I don't get it's capital.

This is my `country-dropdown.blade.php` code

```html
<div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <select id="wilaya" wire:model="selectedCountry" class="w-full dropdown-toggle  items-center justify-between rounded-lg border border-jacarta-100
             bg-white py-3 px-3 dark:border-jacarta-600 dark:bg-jacarta-700 dark:text-jacarta-300">
            <option value="" selected>---Choisir---</option>
            @foreach ($countries as $wilaya)
            <option value="{{ $wilaya->id }}">{{ $wilaya->nom }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is my `capital-dropdown.blade.php` code :

```html
<div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <select class="w-full dropdown-toggle  items-center justify-between rounded-lg border border-jacarta-100
            bg-white py-3 px-3 dark:border-jacarta-600 dark:bg-jacarta-700 dark:text-jacarta-300">
                <option value="">Choisissez la commune</option>
                @foreach($capitals as $commune)
                <option value="{{ $commune->id }}">{{ $commune->nom }}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I haven't tried anything since I am new to livewire and I still don't understand what is the issues ?
So Please feel free to help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Livewire 3, you must apply some changes because your code is made for Livewire 2.

In Livewire 3 *wire:model* is deferred by default, so you must add the *live* modifier to it. Also instead of *emit()* you must use *dispatch()*.

In *country-dropdown.blade.php* apply this change:

```html
<select id="wilaya" wire:model.live="selectedCountry" ....
```

and I suppose that you will also add a *wire:model* to the *capital-dropdown*.

*CountryDropdown.php*

```php
class CountryDropdown extends Component
{
    public $selectedCountry;


    public function updatedSelectedCountry($id) {
        $this->dispatch('countrySelected', countryId: $this->selectedCountry);
    }


    public function render()
    {
        $countries = Wilaya::all();
        return view('livewire.country-dropdown', compact('countries'));
    }
}
```

*CapitalDropdown.php*

```php
class CapitalDropdown extends Component
{
    protected $selectedCountry = null;
    public $capitals;

    protected $listeners = ['countrySelected' => 'setCountry'];


    public function setCountry($countryId)
    {
        $this->selectedCountry = $countryId;
    }


    public function render()
    {
        $this->capitals = Commune::where('wilaya_id', $this->selectedCountry)->get();

        return view('livewire.capital-dropdown');
    }
}
```

Instead of $listeners you can also use the [#[On]](https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/events#listening-for-events) php attribute:

```php
.....
use Livewire\Attributes\On;

class CapitalDropdown extends Component
{
    .....        

    #[On('countrySelected')]
    public function setCountry($countryId)
    {
        $this->selectedCountry = $countryId;
    }

    .....
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried adding a wire:change event on the country then point it to a function that will have this instead?

```
$this->capitals = Commune::where('wilaya_id', $this->selectedCountry)->get();
```

Comment: Also, is the dropdown on the same view? if it is, try to only use 1 component, then make the events in that same component

Comment: how to do that? I am a bit new to livewire ?